# error of unused argument(T) in ifelse in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I try to reverse the boolean vector with ifelse:

```
labels <- disease%>% 
  select(humansAffected)%>%
  is.na()%>%
  ifelse(T, F,T)
```

However, I got an error: Error in ifelse(., labels == T, F, T) : unused argument (T)
even if I changed to :

```
labels <- disease%>% 
    select(humansAffected)%>%
    is.na()%>%
    ifelse(labels==T,"FALSE","TRUE")
```

it shows error: Error in ifelse(., labels == T, "FALSE", "TRUE") : unused argument ("TRUE").

But when I write like this, I got the result I want:

```
labels <- disease%>% 
  select(humansAffected)%>%
  is.na()
ifelse(labels==T,F,T)
```

I want to know why I can't get the answer when I write them together by using %>%?

Comment: You need to use [`filter`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html) and [`mutate`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html)

Comment: Welcome to SO - to help people contribute better answers, I'd suggest including a reprex - here's a post that outlines how and why - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Without a sample of your data, it's difficult to understand exactly what you need, but I hope this example will point you in the right direction.

```
library(dplyr)
disease %>% 
    select(humansAffected) %>%
    filter(!is.na(humansAffected)) %>%
    mutate(humansAffected = ifelse(humansAffected == TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one column in the final dataframe use `transmute`. You can negate `is.na` to get `FALSE` for `NA` and `TRUE` for non-NA.

```
library(dplyr)
disease <- disease %>% transmute(new_col = !is.na(humansAffected))
```

In base R, you can do :

```
disease <- transform(disease, new_col = !is.na(humansAffected))
```

and then select the columns that you want.